# Can't get Safenote to open; freezes on loading screen

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, performance

I've had the Safenote app for quite a while now and have a lot of useful notes in there. But now it won't open—it's frozen on the loading screen. Is there any way of getting it working again?

I'm using an iPhone 4 running iOS 5.

Comment: Did you recently upgrade to iOS 5, or has it been iOS 5 for a while?

Answer (score 1):

If Lizzan's suggestion doesn't work try rebooting your phone by holding down the power button and sliding to power off. That can free up additional memory that may allow you to run it again.

Answer (score 0):

Try double-clicking the home button to bring up your recently used apps at the bottom. Tap and hold on the safenote app until it starts to wiggle, then tap the red - button to force close it. Then try opening the app again and see if it loads correctly.